# How to change the refreshInterval for JMS client programmatically

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I need to be able to update the refreshInterval for JMS client programmatically.

I tried to do it through JmsConfiguration bean, but that's useless, and I couldn't find any configuration on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory class that I could use to update that value.

Comment: what refresh interval are you referring to?

Comment: when JMS client can't create a connection to the broker, it reconnects every 5 seconds (default refresh interval). thats the interval im talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `recoveryInterval` property on the `ActiveMQComponent/JmsComponent` or set the same property on the `JmsConfiguration` POJO.

However, since the Camel ActiveMQ/JMS consumer is based on a Spring JMS listeners, like `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, you cannot simply change that parameter during runtime (if that's what you intend). You need to set the recoveryInterval before the route is created. You can of course recreate the route and possibly ActiveMQ component and have the recovery interval set programmatically.

If you **really** need this feature, you can subclass [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setRecoveryInterval(long)) to allow  setRecoveryInterval to actually trigger during runtime (not sure how easy that is, there is some thread handling to watch out for). Your custom MLC can be supplied to camel via the **messageListenerContainerFactoryRef** option.

Comment: yes i need it at runtime, so i guess its not an option. thanks.

Comment: Aha. Updated with some info on how you can proceed. Not straight forward but possible.

Comment: Thanks Petter, I will give this a try, or maybe try to avoid changing the recovery interval at runtime altogether.